# setEntries of MultiSelectListPreference in Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-resources, android-multiselectlistpreference

I've a problem and don't know the way out of it at the moment. I hope someone could help me with my issue.

I want to let the user check, which contacts he want to add to a preference.
The preference is needed for sending sms to the given contacts. 
I initialize my **MultiSelectListPreference** in a xml like this:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference 
     android:key="sourcecontacts"
     android:entries="@array/contacts"
     android:entryValues="@array/contacts"
     android:title="@string/source_contact" 
     />
```

In my Activity I have an **OnPreferenceClickListener** which should call the method ***manageContacts()*** if the MultiSelectListPreference is clicked.

In this method I want to read any contacts of the device and put them into the MultiSelectListPreference that the user can mark those contacts, which should be inserted into the SharedPrefs.

Now my problem is, that I add the entries to the ListPreference but in the UI I can't see any entries.

Do I have to reload the View or the component?

I look forward to helpful answers.

You'll find my manageContact method below:

```
private void manageContacts() {
    if (entryValues == null || entries == null || entries.length <= 1
        || entryValues.length <= 1) {
        Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        startManagingCursor(contacts);
        entryValues = new CharSequence[contacts.getCount()];
        entries = new CharSequence[contacts.getCount()];
        int ix = 0;
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID }, null,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String contactNumber = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contactName = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (contactNumber != null && !contactNumber.isEmpty()) {
                entries[ix] = contactName;
                entryValues[ix] = contactNumber;
                ix++;
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
    }
    MultiSelectListPreference sourceContacts = (MultiSelectListPreference)
            getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("sourcecontacts");
    MultiSelectListPreference targetContacts = (MultiSelectListPreference)
            getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("targetcontacts");
    if (entries != null && entryValues != null && entries.length >= 1
        && entryValues.length >= 1) {
        sourceContacts.setSelectable(true);
        targetContacts.setSelectable(true);
        sourceContacts.setEntries(entries);
        sourceContacts.setEntryValues(entryValues);
        targetContacts.setEntries(entries);
        targetContacts.setEntryValues(entryValues);
    } else {
        sourceContacts.setSelectable(false);
        targetContacts.setSelectable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are populating `entries` and `entryValues` in a separate thread, which hasn't done anything by the time you test to see if there are any `entries` to add to `sourceContacts` and `targetContacts`. The dialog stops the user from doing anything, but it doesn't stop the main thread from carrying on. Move everything below `}).start();` into the last `runOnUiThread`'s `Runnable`.

Comment: for testing-issues I moved the setter-section in the running thread. In Ui thread and in normal thread. Same Issue..

Comment: I guess you should change the code in your question then, because its currently hiding the real problem - `entries` and `entryValues` will always be empty in the code as it currently stands (at the time the `if` statement checks them i mean).

Comment: thanks. Code edited. Now the thread-things aren't in the post anymore. But nevertheless the problem occurs ;)

Comment: Post the code of your preference activity properly formatted please (so no horizontal scrollbar please)